# Flutter: Catch firebase messaging connection

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I implemented fiebase messaging in my flutter application. I am trying to catch it's connection error for example something like this:

```
6.26.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM002025] Failed to connect to direct channel, error: Error Domain=com.google.fcm Code=4 "No internet available, cannot connect to FIRMessaging" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=No internet available, cannot connect to FIRMessaging}
```

but there is no place to catch it. How can i catch firebase messaging connection?

```
final FirebaseMessaging _fcm = FirebaseMessaging();
    _fcm.getToken().then((value) {
      _token = value;
      print("Message token is: $_token");
    }, onError: (err) {
      print("getToken onError is: $err");
    }).catchError((onError) {
      print("getToken catchError is: $onError");
    });
```

Comment: Doesn't `catchError(error)` catch the error?

Comment: It does'nt has catch if your mean is fcm.getToken(), In addition the problem is not in get token...@SalarBahador

Comment: so where is the problem exactly?

Comment: How can I know that,  If connection is not connected ?@SalarBahador